# Application services performance

Tags: spring, websocket

I am developing one distributed system application, besides than other thing, it use real time messasing to chat service and push notifications to many concurrent users notifications.

First, my actual project system is one Spring Framework Webservices with another two servers, one to real time messaging service, and another Google Cloud Messages to push notifications service.

Now, I am thinking to implement my own real time messaging and push notifications through my Spring Framework Webservices.

In here I have some doubts about application performance, Android/iOS chat and notifications services allways will be in up on Movile Services (like facebook, twitter, whatssap...). To few concurrent users less than 1000 for example, I have not doubt about it would be necessary a low features server to run system, but, if will be to many concurrent users more than 10000 running persistent websockets... Somebody can tell me the features server to run it?

For each Websocket connection Java getting up one persistent new Thread until close connection or only is getting up one new Thread by server to each Websocket request/response?

Which of the above two implementations is better?

Thank you in advance and best regards.

Answer (score 1):

Neither nor;) You will want a server that does not need a new thread per connection or request, but per CPU core. And do asynchronous networking. E.g. Netty or Jetty.

Comment: You can add Tomcat to that list. JSR-356 based WebSocket implementation are based on Servlet 3.1 non-blocking IO capability.

Answer (score 0):

Play Framework would be a perfect fit for this : full asynchronous/non blocking and very good websocket support.